# Information Asymmetry in capital markets: EU ad-hoc announcements/8-K filings in other countries

Tags: investment, asymmetric-information, trading

In many countries, companies whose securities are traded on a stock exchange are subject to an ad-hoc disclosure requirement. This ad-hoc announcement publication duty refers to the obligation to immediately publish insider information that is potentially price-relevant for the company's securities in order to reduce information asymmetries between coporate insiders (like managers) and investors.
For companies in the European Union, these corporate disclosures are called “ad-hoc announcements” and are defined in the MAR (Market Abuse Regulation). For companies in the US, these corporate disclosures are called “8-K Filings” respectively “6-K Filings” and are defined in The Securities Exchange Act of 1934.

I am searching now for similar regulations in other countries, i.e. does anyone know how such compulsory corporate disclosures are called and in which law they are codified in other countries?
I am especially interested in the regulations of further G7 countries (i.e. Japan, Canada, United Kingdom) and possibly also further G20 countries (i.e. Argentina, Australia, Brazil, India, Indonsesia, Japan, Mexico, Russia, Saudi Arabia, South Africa, South Korea, Turkey, China).